# Ruby class 'split' not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to use the split class to split up an array. I keep getting this error:

```
MethodError (undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass):
```

This is what I'm trying to do:
 def create

```
    @listing.landlord = current_landlord
    if @listing.save
      photo_id_array = params[:images].split(/,/)
      photo_id_array.each do |image|
        @image = Photo.find_by_id("photo.id")
        @image.listing_id = @listing.id
      end
      render :show, :status => 200
    else
      render :status => 403, :json => {:errors => @listing.errors}
    end
  end
```

I'm running Rails 3.2.9. Any ideas into what may be causing this?

Edit:

Here is the full post:

```
Started POST "/listings" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-12 01:04:52 -0800
Processing by ListingsController#create as application/json; charset=utf-8
  Parameters: {"listing"=>{"street_address"=>"123 main st", "city"=>"los angeles", "state"=>"ca", "availability"=>"12 Dec 2012", "price"=>"2000", "period"=>"2", "category"=>"1", "cats"=>"false", "dogs"=>"false", "square_footage"=>"0", "bedrooms"=>"3", "bathrooms"=>"2", "short_description"=>"tree-lined street", "long_description"=>"big yard", "images"=>["70621", "70622", "70620"]}, "auth_token"=>"6489Cn7KeTmejSxaWsws"}
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
  User Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."authentication_token" = '6489Cn7KeTmejSxaWsws' LIMIT 1
  Landlord Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "landlords".* FROM "landlords" WHERE "landlords"."authentication_token" = '6489Cn7KeTmejSxaWsws' LIMIT 1
  Role Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."name" = 'admin' LIMIT 1
  Role Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "landlords_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "landlords_roles"."role_id" WHERE "landlords_roles"."landlord_id" = 5867 AND "roles"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 275ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/listings_controller.rb:8:in `create'


  Rendered /Users/rigelstpierre/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.9ms)
  Rendered /Users/rigelstpierre/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (2.1ms)
  Rendered /Users/rigelstpierre/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (16.9ms)
```

Comment: @apneadiving It doensn't look like it. Take a look at the post.

Comment: As said by @apneadiving you are getting nil for params[:images] and also FYI array does not have a method split

Comment: @soundar Is there a way to iterate over each of items in the array?

Comment: `Array#each`.  For example: `some_array.each {|item| puts item}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`params[:images]` is nil, you're after `params[:listing][:images]` I assume.

Your params are structured like: `"listing"=>{"images"=>["70621", "70622", "70620"]}`.

Plus, you needn't split it, it's an array. Access each item of the array with: `params[:listing][:images].each do |i|`

Comment: Can I iterate over it I'm wanting to look up each item and and assign the listing_id to it.

Comment: Yep. Either do it like you were trying in your post: `images_array = params[:listing][:images]; images_array.each do |i| ...` or as above in my post.

Answer (score 6):

Use:

```
params[:listing][:images]
```

And it's already an Array, no need to split. You can directly do: `params[:listing][:images].each`.